# Bash negation of -a (file exists) does not change result, whereas for ! -e changes result

Tags: bash, test

I'm perplexed but still guess I misunderstood Bash somehow.

```
/$ if [   -e /bin/grep ]; then echo yea; else echo nay ; fi
yea
/$ if [ ! -e /bin/grep ]; then echo yea; else echo nay ; fi
nay
/$ if [   -a /bin/grep ]; then echo yea; else echo nay ; fi
yea
/$ if [ ! -a /bin/grep ]; then echo yea; else echo nay ; fi
yea
```

Why negation `!` reverses effect of `-e` test but not `-a` test?

Man bash says:

#### [test](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-test):

> #### 3 arguments
>
> The  following  conditions are applied in the order listed.
>
> 1. If the second argument is one of the binary conditional
>    operators listed above under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS, the result of the expression is the result of the binary test using the first
>    and  third  arguments as operands.  The `-a` and `-o` operators are considered binary operators when there are three arguments.
> 2. If the first argument is `!`, the value is the negation of the two-argument test using the second and third arguments.

#### [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

> Conditional expressions are used by the `[[`
> compound command and the `test` and `[` builtin commands
>
> `-a file`
> True if file exists.
> `-b file`
> True if file exists and is a block special file.
> `-c file`
> True if file exists and is a character special file.
> `-d file`
> True if file exists and is a directory.
> `-e file`
> True if file exists.

Comment: [bash if -a vs -e option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321348/5291015)

Comment: `if [ ! -a /bin/gxxx ]; then echo yey; else echo ney; fi` also returns `yey` demonstrating that `! -a` is not "_not `-a`_"

Comment: @Inian, thank you. google have not shown that QA in top results, I searched for "bash negation and -a test results"

Comment: It isn't really relevant here, but these words are conventionally spelled "yea" and "nay."

Comment: @David, it kind of relevant. I was busy tackling the problem and skipped spell-checking. Feel free to edit ;-)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60499503/bash-test-builtin-with-several-arguments-how-are-they-parsed

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`-a` is both a unary (for `a`ccessible, added for compatibility with the Korn shell, but otherwise non-standard and now redundant with `-e`) and binary (for `a`nd, in POSIX (with XSI) but deprecated there) operator.

Here `[ ! -a /bin/grep ]` invokes the *binary* operator as required by POSIX. It's `[ "$a" -a "$b" ]` to test whether `$a` is non-empty *and* `$b` is non empty, here with `$a` == `!` and `$b` == `/bin/grep`. As both strings are non-empty, it returns *true*.

See also the *"The -a and -o operators are considered binary operators when there are three arguments"* in the text you quoted.

`-a` is deprecated in both the unary and binary form, the unary one because it's superseded by `-e`, the binary one because it makes for unreliable and ambiguous test expressions.

To test for file existence (though in effect, it's more a test whether the file is *accessible*, whether `stat()` would succeed on the path¹), use `[ -e filepath ]`. To *and* two conditions, use `&&` between two invocations of `[`.

To test whether a string is non empty, I personally prefer the `[ -n "$string" ]` form over the `[ "$string" ]` one.

So:

- test for file existence:

  ```
  [ -e "$file" ]   # not [ -a "$file" ]
  [ ! -e "$file" ] # not [ ! -a "$file" ]
  ```
- test for two strings being non-empty:

  ```
  [ -n "$a" ] && [ -n "$b" ] # not [ "$a" -a "$b" ]
  [ "$a" ] && [ "$b" ]
  ```

From [the rationale in the POSIX specification for the `test` (aka `[`) utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

> The XSI extensions specifying the -a and -o binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent. (Many expressions
> using them are ambiguously defined by the grammar depending on the specific expressions being evaluated.) Scripts using these expressions
> should be converted to the forms given below. Even though many implementations will continue to support these obsolescent forms, scripts
> should be extremely careful when dealing with user-supplied input that could be confused with these and other primaries and operators.

and:

> An early proposal used the KornShell -a primary (with the same meaning), but this was changed to -e because there were concerns about the high probability of humans confusing the -a primary with the -a binary operator.

The manuals of `yash`, `bosh`, GNU `coreutils` do guard against using binary `-a`/`-o` in their respective `[`/`test` implementations and `zsh`'s manual never documented them², but many others including `bash` (the GNU shell) unfortunately still don't discourage their usage nor deprecate them.

---

<sup>¹ more on that in [this answer of mine to a related stackoverflow Q&A](//stackoverflow.com/a/40046642)</sup>

<sup>² a `test`/`[` builtin was only added to zsh in version 2.0.3 in 1991. The `[[ ... ]]` special construct, from the Korn shell was always preferred there, and has its own syntax where `&&` and `||` are used for *and* and *or* operators.</sup>

Comment: thank you. Is there an efficient way to update `bash` man pages in mainstream distros to add `deprecated` word to `-a` to avoid confusion of people like myself?

Comment: @Martian2020, that would definitely be a good idea. I would suggest you raise it upstreams at bug-bash@gnu.org

Answer (score 13):

Bash parses `[ ! -a WORD ]` with `-a` being the binary operator meaning “and”, surrounded by two single-word tests which are true if non-empty. Thus `[ ! -a "" ]` is false and `[ ! -a WORD ]` is true if `WORD` is non-empty.

This parsing conforms to the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_05) (although strictly speaking it wouldn't have to since unary `-a` is not specified by POSIX). Incidentally, mksh and zsh parse this case in the same way, but ksh93 parses it with unary `!` followed by unary `-a`.

To avoid the ambiguity, don't use the deprecated `-a` operator, use the standard `-e` operator, which doesn't have an identically-spelled binary operator. Also, to avoid ambiguity or errors in longer corner cases, use `&&` and `||` as binary operators (either outside `[ … ]` or inside `[[ … ]]`) instead of the potentially ambiguous `-a`/`-o` inside `[ … ]`.

Comment: Good catch about ksh93. I've raised [a bug about it](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/330)

Comment: Looks like `test` from GNU coreutils has a related bug for `[ ! -o x ]`.